# Not able to start zookeeper thus apache kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I downloaded Kafka on my local pc windows for development and it comes with zookeeper in it. When I try to start zookeeper using the below command, I'm getting  the below error.

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
```

and it gives me error message

> `error missing 'server' jvm at 'C:\Program Files
>   <x86>\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\server\jvm.dll' please install or use the
>   JRE or JDK that contains those missing components.`

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: download java from oracle site and install it and add it to env variables

Comment: which java you mean? I have jdk and jre 1.8.0.60 ...is there something else I need to download? can you provide me with links and steps for adding in env variables plz?

Comment: Can you run java and javac in command line

Comment: Why are you not using the most recent version of Java 8? Plus, you might want to check out https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Answer (score 0):

RE: the question, seems Java is not installed properly. I generally use Ninite website to get Java as it'll ensure you get the latest version (which you'll want 64-bit Java anyway)

> im running zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties from bin/windows folder in kafka folder

If you are currently in the `bin/windows` folder, run `dir`... Do you see a config folder there? That is what the error is telling you; that that folder & config file do not exist.

You can either reference `..\config\zookeeper.properties`, or move up a folder to where you extracted Kafka (let's say `C:\kafka` for example), and you should be able to run like so

```
C:\kafka> bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

As @Deadpool mentions, though, it might help if you setup a `KAFKA_HOME` variable, then you can do this from any location

```
%KAFKA_HOME%\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat %KAFKA_HOME%\config\zookeeper.properties
```